# Elasticsearch nested aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to pull some metrics from the below Elasticsearch model.

Mapping:

```
{
"properties":{
    "createdAt":{
        "type":"long"
    },
    "updatedAt":{
        "type":"long"
    },
    "tags": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "groupId": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "accountId": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    },
    "records":{
        "type":"nested",
        "properties":{
            "count":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "recordTags":{
                "type":"nested",
                "properties":{
                    "name":{
                        "type":"keyword"
                    },
                    "enabled":{
                        "type":"boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Sample Records:

Record -1 :

```
{
"_id": "05b7a31833f821d80f0df98fbf39be3815d"
"createdAt":1619540790808,
"updatedAt":1619540798261,
"tags" : {
    "groupId" : "abe0326-41d2-9a82-79c68ef50761",
    "accountId" : "08747"
},
"records":[
    {
        "count": 2,
        "recordTags": {
            "name" : "RECO_1",
            "enabled" : true,            
        }
        
    },
    {
        "count": 3,
        "recordTags": {
            "name" : "RECO_2",
            "enabled" : true,            
        }
        
    }
]
```

}

Record-2:

```
{
"_id": "7a31833f821d80f0df98fbf39be3815d"
"createdAt":1619540790808,
"updatedAt":1619540798261,
"tags" : {
    "groupId" : "abe0326-41d2-9a82-79c68ef50761",
    "accountId" : "08747"
},
"records":[
    {
        "count": 2,
        "recordTags": {
            "name" : "RECO_1",
            "enabled" : true,            
        }
        
    },
    {
        "count": 3,
        "recordTags": {
            "name" : "RECO_2",
            "enabled" : true,            
        }
        
    }
]
```

}

I want to aggregate the records by recordTags.name and show the sum of the records.count field.
Ex:
RECO_1 (count: 4)

RECO_2 (count: 6)

Tried this aggregation query, but it is not working as expected.

/_search

```
{
"size":0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "tags",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "tags.accountId": "08747"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs":{
    "distinct_groups":{
        "nested":{
            "path":"tags"
        },
        "aggs":{
            "account_id":{
                "terms":{
                    "field":"tags.accountId"
                },
                "aggs":{
                    "groupId":{
                        "terms":{
                            "field":"tags.groupId"
                        },
                        "aggs":{
                            "distinct_records":{
                                "nested":{
                                    "path":"records.recordTags"
                                },
                                "aggs":{
                                    "interction":{
                                        "terms":{
                                            "field":"records.recordTags.name"
                                        }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can you please help me with how can I get the records.count for the specified aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

Once you're aggregating within *one* `nested` context and are about to jump into a *different* nested context, you'll need to first **escape the current context**. That's done through the [`reverse_nested` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html), i.e.:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "tags.accountId": "08747"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_groups": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "account_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.accountId"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "groupId": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.groupId"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "back_to_top": {
                  "reverse_nested": {},      <--- empty options mean that you're jumping to the doc root
                  "aggs": {
                    "distinct_records": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "records.recordTags"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "interction": {
                          "terms": {
                            "field": "records.recordTags.name"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Joe, for sharing your thoughts. The suggested query is not grouping the records as required.

I am looking for result something like the format shown below, but I am not able to get the aggregated sum of count field after grouping.

`AccountId--08747
>>>>>GroupId--abe0326-41d2-9a82-79c68ef50761
>>>>>>>>>>RECO_1
>>>>>>>>>>count:4
>>>>>>>>>>RECO_2
>>>>>>>>>>count:6
>>>>>GroupId--23e0326-41d2-9a82-79c68ef50761
>>>>>>>>>>RECO_1
>>>>>>>>>>count:1
>>>>>>>>>>RECO_2
>>>>>>>>>>count:2
`